# Pasar Datos de Modal a vista normal [Angukar]

Tags: angular

Estoy terminando un proyecto,que no está todo documentado, necesito pasar datos de un modal a la vista normal, estos datos los toma de un archivo.ts

este es el código de la vista normal, se manda a llamar con el (click) en el button y trae el modal

```
                    <div class="bot">
                        <button class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" style="float:left;" (click)="getMenu(restaurant.id)">{{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_details" | translate}}</button>

                        <a style="display: none;" [routerLink]="['/restaurant-reservation', restaurant.id]" class="awe-btn awe-btn-13" *ngIf="restaurant.only_reservation">{{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_reservar" | translate}}</a>
                    </div>

            <p-dialog 
                header="{{restaurantActual['nombre']}}" 
                [(visible)]="displayModal" 
                [modal]="true" 
                [style]="{width: '80vw'}">
                <div style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="loadingModal">
                    <i class="pi pi-spin pi-spinner" style="font-size: 3em"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="restaurant-tabs" *ngIf="!loadingModal">
                    <div class="tabs tabs-restaurant" >
                        <div class="icon-restaurant text-center"><i class="lotus-icon-calendar"></i></div>
                        <h2 class="lbl-rest-section text-center">
                            <strong>{{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_dias" | translate}}</strong>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="tabview-container" *ngIf="restaurantActual['aperturas'][0].length > 0; else noDays">
                            <a 
                                *ngIf="enable_scroll_days" 
                                href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                class="tabview-scroll-btn tabview-scroll-btn-left" 
                                (click)="scrollPrevious('tabview-custom-days')">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p-dialog>
            <!-- END / ITEM -->
```

Necesito que los datos del modal se impriman sin necesidad de abrirlo, ya que se eliminará
este es el .component.ts donde viene el "getMenu" que es lo que necesito imprimir fuera del modal

```
getMenu(id:number){
this.displayModal = true;
this.loadingModal = true;
this.idRestaurante = id;
for(var i=0; i<this.restaurants.length; i++){
  if(this.idRestaurante == this.restaurants[i].id){
    this.restaurantActual = this.restaurants[i];
  }
}
this._restaurantService.getPlatillos(this.lang,id).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.menu = this.groupBy(response, 'categoria');

      this._restaurantService.getPoliciesByRestaurant(this.lang, id).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.policies = response.politicas;
          this.loadingModal = false;
          setTimeout(() => {      
            this.enable_scroll_days = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-days");
            this.enable_scroll_menu = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-menu");
          }, 100);              
        },
        error => {
          this.displayModal = false;
          this.error = true;
        }
      );
    },
    error => {
      this.displayModal = false;
      this.error = true;
    }
);

this.enable_scroll_days = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-days");
this.enable_scroll_menu = this.verifyEnableCustomSideScroll("tabview-custom-menu");
```

}

[image: Esa es la información que necesito que se imprima sin usar el modal]

Comment: Hola Jhonny Eliezer. No puedo ver todo el código, pero deduzco que estás usando PrimeNg(el que uso diariamente), lo que quieres es mostrar la página principal, los datos del o los restaurante/s, ya seleccionado, me imagino que el id estará accesible, puedes crear un método y llamarlo ngOninit, si tiene datos que los muestre, puedes añadir otro parámetro más, para decir cuando se muestra el modal, cuando se inicie la página con id, que se llene restaurante y muestre las opciones en cambio si le das, al botón que abra el modal, espero haber aclarado algo.

Comment: Si, la idea es mostrar la info de los restaurantes al entrar a la web,( los datos los toma de una api ya generada) , sin necesidad de usar el modal, (porque se va a quitar) usaré el método que me comentas

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola Jhony, no digo de quitarlo, solo usar el modal cuando te haga falta, por que no se si también se puede usar para modificar o crear algún dato, como una reserva. Espero haberme explicado.

Comment: Hola Juan, en este caso lo que busco es quitar el modal y que esa info este normal, debajo de otra llamada que tengo, en el cual llamo nombre-foto-descripción del restaurante, solo necesito llamar los menús debajo de eso